# Не могу установить модуль Python "Pygame"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
C:\Users\mapk0>pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/9c/78626be04e193c0624842090fe5555b3805c050dfaa81c8094d6441db2be/pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\mapk0\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mapk0\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-uxamm092\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mapk0\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-uxamm092\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\mapk0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uxamm092\pygame\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\mapk0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uxamm092\pygame\
    Complete output (17 lines):


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...


    Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\mapk0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uxamm092\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\mapk0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uxamm092\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\mapk0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uxamm092\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\mapk0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uxamm092\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3.8 еще не поддерживает pygame скачайте python 3.7.x и все будет нормально установлено. Ссылка на python 3.7.5 -- https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-375/ - последняя релиз версия 3.7

Comment: В целом, хорошая идея пробовать устанавливать не на последнюю версию Python. Если последняя Python 3.11 - то пробовать на 3.10.

Comment: @insolor Не в этом суть, разработчики библиотек не всегда успевают выпустить поддержку актуальных версий. И единственное решение это иметь актуальную версию под зависимости проекта (а работать выбирая версию Python через virtualenv)

Comment: Также рекомендую смотреть актуальную поддерживаемую версию на PyPi

Comment: "разработчики библиотек не всегда успевают выпустить поддержку актуальных версий" - я это и подразумевал, просто пропустил этот логический шаг.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по

```
command: 'c:\users\mapk0\appdata\local\programs\python\python38
```

Это `python 3.8`. (В следующий раз, пожалуйста, указывайте версии всех компонент)

Аналогичный вопрос про `python 3.8` и `pygame` был задан недавно на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58489348/unable-to-install-pygame-on-python-3-8-via-pip-windows-10).
Вот краткий пересказ ответа, который мне кажется полезным, на случай, если вы не понимаете английский:

`pip` вообще-то не дружит с `pygame`.
Но его можно скомпилировать с помощью инструкций отсюда: https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows (англ.)
При этом, для установки с версией 3.8 вам нужно использовать `pygame 2.0.0` и инструкции под заголовком SDL2.

Если вам удастся установить `pygame` с помощью этих инструкций, желательно проголосовать за 2-ой ответ в оригинальном вопросе. Или отпишитесь здесь в комментарии, и я за него проголосую.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы установить pygame нужен python 3.7 который можно скачать с https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.9/python-3.7.9-amd64.exe

Comment: А в принятом ответе разве не тоже самое? Зачем вы его дублируете?

Answer (score 0):

Cтолкнулся с такой же проблемой при установке pygame на `python 3.11.1`.

нашёл решение на иноязычном портале `stackoverflow`:

```
pip install pygame --
```

Вписываем в `cmd` данную команду и всё устанавливается.